# ttys0 misses/garbles data while ttyusb0 does not

Tags: c, ubuntu, serial-port, termios

A program in c using termios works well if the port is ttyusb0, but misses/garbles data if got through ttys0 i.e comport com1.

proogram runs under ubuntu 9.04 & 10.04

Please suggest the remedies cause for this discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

Garbled serial data is usually due to using the wrong serial speed. The default might be different for the usb port vs normal serial port. Are you calling `cfsetispeed` and `cfsetospeed`?

Comment: speed setting is being done using this statement:- new_port_settings.c_cflag = baudr | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;with baudr being B19200 and is same for both.thnx

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same serial cable for both tests?  At higher baud rates, a bad cable can result in noise.  If `ttyusb0` has a short cable between the USB adapter and the device, but `ttyS0` is a long ribbon cable, you'd easily see noise on `ttyS0` but not `ttyusb0`.